# Extraction from string - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string. That string is a html code and it serves as a teaser for the blog posts I am creating. The whole html code (teaser) is stored in a field in the database.

My goal: I'd like to make that when a user (facebook like social button) likes certain blog post, right data is displayed on his news feeds. In order to do that I need to extract from the teaser in the first occurrence of an image an image path inside `src="i-m-a-g-e--p-a-t-h"`. I succeeded when a user puts only one image in teaser, but if he accidentally puts two images or more the whole thing craches.
Furthermore, for description field I need to extract text inside the first occurrence inside `<p>` tag. The problem is also that a user can put an image inside the first tag.

I would very much appreciate if an expert could help me resolve this what's been bugging me for days.

Text string with a regular expression for extracting src can be found here: http://rubular.com/r/gajzivoBSf

Thanks!

Comment: So, um... how do you use that website? Where's the "submit" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to parse HTML by yourself. Let the professionals do it.

```
require 'nokogiri'
frag = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment( your_html_string )
first_img_src = frag.at_css('img')['src']
first_p_text  = frag.at_css('p').text
```

Comment: Phrogz, thanks, this was very helpful, and it all works great in my rails console. But when I put my code in .html.erb script, i constantly have different problems with Nokogiri and I'm getting messages like: "uninitialized constant Refinery::Blog::Post::Nokogiri" Do you know the cause of this and how to resolve it. Google didn't help concerning this matter

Comment: @Dantes It sounds like you have not added `require 'nokogiri'` in the right spot.

Comment: I tried to add it everywhere - in Gemfile, at the top of the model (post.rb), inside the method I created in model, inside the view... - none of this functions. Can you tell me where is 'the right spot'?